# Escape LaTeX Characters in Python3 Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, latex, tex

I have a dictionary that needs to have values properly escaped for LaTeX consumption.

Steps:

Get some JSON from a text file into a python dictionary.

```
d1 = {'a': 'art', 'b': 'a_$b', 'c': ['_#', 'h'], 'd': {'e': 4, 'f#_a': {'g': '^_$#&'}}}
```

Make a dictionary of all items to convert:

```
tex = {
    '&':  '\&',
    '%':  '\%', 
    '$':  '\$', 
    '#':  '\#', 
    '_':  '\_', 
    '^':  '\^', 
}
```

Make `d2` from `d1` and `tex`, noting that only leaf nodes are escaped:

```
>>>> d2 = unknown code here
>>>> d2
{'a': 'art', 'b': 'a\_\$b', 'c': ['\_\#', 'h'], 'd': {'e': 4, 'f#_a': {'g': '\^\_\$\#\&'}}}
```

Here is a messy rough draft of my attempt so far. As you can see, I am stuck on recreating `d2`.

```
def texEscape(originalKey, d):                                                                                                              
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for k, v in d.items():
            if isinstance(v, str):
                print(k)
                print(v)
                print()
            else:
                texEscape(originalKey, v)
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for i in d:
            texEscape(originalKey, i)
    else:
        print(originalKey)
        print(d)
        print()
```

Comment: what have you already tried/have you tried anything?

Comment: I have tried looping through the dictionary and checking whether `i` is an instance of `dict`, `list`, or `str`, and was able to convert the leaf nodes appropriately. I got stuck on recreating d2.

Comment: ahhh okay, i see now. give me a sec, i wil try to put somethign together

Comment: why do you have `'_':  '\letterunderscore{}' in `tex` but `'b': 'a\_\$b'` just has a regular backslash?

Comment: Simplified; thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Side note: although these particular characters work okay, it's good practice to use raw strings such as `r'\&'` when literal backslashes are wanted.

Answer (score 0):

originally i was just going to do a dict comprehension where every value as a string was being replaced using `tex` but I didn't realize you had nested lists,dicts. This works.

```
>>> tex = {
            '&':  '\&',
            '%':  '\%',
            '$':  '\$',
            '#':  '\#',
            '_':  '\_',
            '^':  '\^',
        }
>>> def change(x):
    key,value = x
    if isinstance(value, dict):
        return key,dict(map(change,value.items()))
    elif isinstance(value, list):
        return key,[''.join(tex[c] if c in tex else c for c in str(x)) for x in value]
    else:
        return key,''.join(tex[c] if c in tex else c for c in str(value))
>>> d1 = {'a': 'art', 'b': 'a_$b', 'c': ['_#', 'h'], 'd': {'e': 4, 'f#_a': {'g': '^_$#&'}}}
>>> d2 = dict(map(change,d1.items()))
>>> d2
{'b': 'a\\_\\$b', 'd': {'e': '4', 'f#_a': {'g': '\\^\\_\\$\\#\\&'}}, 'c': ['\\_\\#', 'h'], 'a': 'art'}
```

it seems kinda crazy but what it does is iterate through each value of `d1` as a `key,value` tuple, assess what type it is, then change each value as necessary. is it the simplest solution? probably not. But it works and is pythonic in the sense that it doesnt import any external modules

Comment: This results in an error: `TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, int found`

Comment: my bad, the edit reflects this but the list comprehension in the else was using `x` rather than `value`. and theres now an explicit cast to `str(value)`

Comment: For some reason your example returns two backslashes each? Also, it is not quite robust enough: e.g. `d1 = {'a': 'art', 'b': 'a_$b', 'c': ['_#', {'f':1}], 'd': {'e': 4, 'f#_a': {'g': '^_$#&'}}}`

Comment: yeah i realized it is not the most robust because i had thought if a list was found that i can assume it to not contain anything nested. i will change to fit. the 2 backslashes is just to show that there are backslashes there, the raw string really only has one

Comment: If this question is changed to fit, I would be willing to accept it as the right answer.